# Am I correctly using the request module in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I need to make an POST request of type "application/json" to some URL

Here is the request format

```
{
  "Subject": "TestSubject",
  "Body": "TestBody",
  "PreferredLanguage": "en-US",
  "Recipients": [
    {
      "FirstName": "TestName",
      "EmailAddress": "TestEmail"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is how I am doing this in my code with the request module, which is not currently working.

```
request.post(
        'https://someURL.com/messages',
        {
            json:
            {
                Subject: "TestSubject",
                Body: "TestBody",
                PreferredLanguage: "en-US",
                Recipients: [
                    {
                        FirstName: "TestName",
                        EmailAddress: "TestEmail"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    )
```

What is wrong with how I am doing this request?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: I am sending the email to myself, and I am not getting anything.

Comment: Is the format correct though?

Comment: `which is not currently working` - well fix it ... seriously, please try to describe the error, or whatever it is that is not working, because "not working" is obvious, you wouldn't be here if it worked

Comment: "is the format correct" ... well what does the API specify is the correct format?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm trying to rule out the possibility of it being due to incorrect use of the request module.

Comment: oh .. which request module specifically?

Comment: The standard "request.js"

Comment: [this one](https://github.com/request/request)?

Comment: OK, so assuming it is that one, the code looks OK - I see your code has no callback... have you tried adding a callback `function (error, response, body) {` ... there's an `error` parameter there, which may enlighten you where it's gone wrong ...

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the callback

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

As explained here: [npmjs requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback)